# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level exit status 1

Tags: python

Been trying to code this problem up but it seems that python detects some indentation problem. Im new to python so please shed some ligh on me. Thanks

```
def findThreeLargestNumbers(array):
    threeLargest = [None, None, None]
    for num in array:
        if num > threeLargest[2] or threeLargest[2] is None:
            threeLargest[0] = threeLargest[1]
            threeLargest[1] = threeLargest[2]
            threeLargest[2] = num
    
        elif num > threeLargest[1] or threeLargest[1] is None:
            threeLargest[0] = threeLargest[1]
            threeLargest[1] = num
    
        elif num > threeLargest[0] or threeLargest[0] is None:
            threeLargest[0] = num
        
    return threeLargest
```

EDIT: I coded it again and it got solved. Thanks anyways.

Comment: This code is fine. The likely problem is with now this definition is indented relative to the preceding or following code.

Comment: As an aside, you might want to look at the `collections` module to see how you can use a `deque`, instead of a list, to implement this. Or, you should look at the `heapq` module, which already solves the problem of finding the `k` largest items in a list.

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the None conditions from your code and used zeros instead.

```
def findThreeLargestNumbers(array):
    
    threeLargest = [0, 0, 0]
    for num in array:
        
        if num > threeLargest[2]:
            threeLargest[0] = threeLargest[1]
            threeLargest[1] = threeLargest[2]
            threeLargest[2] = num
    
        elif num > threeLargest[1]:
            threeLargest[0] = threeLargest[1]
            threeLargest[1] = num
    
        elif num > threeLargest[0]:
            threeLargest[0] = num
        
    return threeLargest
    
print(findThreeLargestNumbers([-1,4,10,55,90]))
```

Comment: You changed the code's logic. And it is quite unnecessary and irrelevant to the question.

Comment: When I tried to used the original code I got an error related to the None value. After changing the logic the code is working and printing correct results.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for highlighting that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).